# How do I create an ActiveRecord relationship to an ActiveResource object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeresource

Let's say I'm writing a Library application for a publishing company who already has a People application.

So in my Library application I have

```
class Person < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://api.people.mypublisher.com/"
end
```

and now I want to store `Article`s for each `Person`:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person, :as => :author
end
```

I imagine I'd have the following table in my database:

```
Articles
id (PK) | title (string) | body (text) | author_id (integer)
```

`author_id` isn't exactly a Foreign-Key, since I don't have a People table.  That leaves several questions:

1. how do I tell my `Person` `ActiveResource` object that it `has_many` `Articles`?
2. Will `Articles.find(:first).author` work?  Will `belongs_to` even work given that there's no `ActiveRecord` and no backing table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you point out, you are giving up a lot because ActiveResource does not have associations in the sense that ActiveRecord does.

You have already found the answer to question #1. As for question #2, your ActiveRecord model Article should behave just fine when configured with a "belongs_to" association to an ActiveResource model. That is Aritcle.find(:first).author should return the person object you want.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose one possibility for #1, assuming I can get any of it working, is to do this:

```
class Person < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://api.people.mypublisher.com/"

  def articles
    Article.find(:all, :conditions => { :person_id => self.id })
  end

  def add_article(article)
    article.person_id = self.id
  end
end
```

But it loses a **lot** of what `has_many` offers.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be making a method that returns a scope.

```
class Person < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = ..
. 
  def articles
    Article.for_person(self.id)
  end
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :for_person, lambda { |pid| { :conditions => { :person_id => pid }}}
end
```