# Can ActiveResource models integrate with ActiveRecord models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rest, activeresource

I'm working on a Rails app that will serve as an authentication system for other Rails apps through Rails's ActiveResource functionality.

The authentication app has an ActiveRecord model called `User`. The client app has an ActiveResource model called `User`. I know that in the client app I can do stuff like `user.save` and it will perform a PUT operation using XML over HTTP.

But what if I want to put into my client app's `User` model `has_many :contacts` or something like that (`contacts` being an ActiveRecord model in the client app)? Then I'd want to do stuff like get all the `Contact`s that belong to some `User`.

Is that possible?

(I noticed that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183604/how-do-i-create-an-activerecord-relationship-to-an-activeresource-object) was asked, but there weren't many responses.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no.  The classes involved in `has_many`, `belongs_to`, `has_and_belongs_to_many` live in ActiveRecord and build SQL queries to make the associations work.

That said, you can make it look like there is an association, you just have to write your own methods.  Which was the up-voted answer on that question you linked to.

So, add a column to your Contact model that is `user_id` or whatever key you need to pass to your `User.find` ActiveResource model and you could part of the association contract like this:

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
  # boilerplate ActiveResource url stuff

  def contacts
    Contact.find(:all, :conditions => { :user_id => self.id })
  end
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Model
  def user
    User.find_by_user_id(self.user_id)
  end
end
```

There's a lot more you get from `has_many` for free, but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 3):

This question is ancient, but I ran across this recently:

http://yetimedia.tumblr.com/post/35233051627/activeresource-is-dead-long-live-activeresource

From the post:

> Basic support for associations: has_many, has_one, belongs_to now can be used in ActiveResource models.

There are some other improvements noted in the posting that may warrant a second look into ActiveResource even though it has been removed from Rails 4.0.

Comment: As of ActiveResource 4.0, it seems associations from ActiveResource to ActiveRecord doesn’t work. I don’t know whether it’s a bug or intended feature though... Or atleast I’m not able to get it work.

Comment: Tumblr post has been removed so unfortunately the link goes to a 404 page.

Comment: The page was archived before if went offline: https://web.archive.org/web/20130402191732/http://yetimedia.tumblr.com/post/35233051627/activeresource-is-dead-long-live-activeresource